# Update Header component to show logout button with NextJS App router

Tags: javascript, authentication, next.js

I am using NextJS 14 with App router with Spring Boot in the backend. I have public and private routes. For the private routes I have a login page. When the user logs in successfully I return a JWT token as a cookie.

This is my root layout

```
import "./global.css";
import Header from "./components/header/header";
import {GlobalProvider} from "./_lib/global-provider"; 
import MainContent from "./components/main-content";

export default async function RootLayout({children}) {

    return (
            <html lang="en" className="">
            <body className="min-h-screen scroll-smooth">
            <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
                <GlobalProvider>
                    <Header/>
                    <MainContent>
                        {children}
                    </MainContent>
                </GlobalProvider>
            </div>
            </body>
            <GoogleAnalytics/>
            </html>
    );
}
```

And this is my Header component that should show a Log Out button when the user is logged in.

```
"use client";

import Link from "next/link";
import {useAdminAuthContext} from "../../_lib/admin-auth-provider";
import LogoHeader from "./logo-header";

export default function Header() {

    const adminAuth = useAdminAuthContext();

    return (
            <header className="sticky top-0 z-50 flex-none bg-gray-50 py-6 drop-shadow">
                <nav className="relative mx-auto flex justify-between px-8 max-sm:px-2">
                    <div className="flex items-center ">
                        <LogoHeader/>
                    </div>

                    <div className="flex items-center">
                        {
                            adminAuth.user != null && <button>LOG OUT</button>
                        }
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
    );
}
```

I am using an AuthContext that exposes logIn and logOut functions that actually calls my backend and saves into a state prop if the user is authenticated.

The problem is that when the page is reloaded, the state is lost and the LOG OUT button disappears.

```
"use client";

import {createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState} from "react";
import {useRouter} from 'next/navigation';

const host = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST;
export const AdminAuthContext = createContext({});
export const AdminAuthProvider = ({children}) => {
    const router = useRouter(); // Initialize useRouter

    const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // State to store admin user details

    const doAdminLogin = async (email, password) => {
        const request = await fetch(`${host}/api/admin/login`, {
            cache: "no-store",
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({email, password}),
        });

        if (!request.ok) {
            console.error('Login failed');
            throw new Error("Error logging in");
        }

        const res = await request.json();
        setUser(res.username);
        router.push('/private/admin/dashboard'); // Use router.push to navigate
    };

    const doAdminLogout = async () => {
        const request = await fetch(`${host}/api/admin/logout`, {
            cache: "no-store",
            method: "POST",
            credentials: "include",
        });
    };

    return (
            <AdminAuthContext.Provider value={{user, doAdminLogin, doAdminLogout}}>
                {children}
            </AdminAuthContext.Provider>
    );
};

export function useAdminAuthContext() {
    return useContext(AdminAuthContext);
}
```

So the question is: What do I need to change so my  component shows the LOG OUT button when the user is logged in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you refresh the page, any state is lost. To remember something from a previous session, you need to use one of the browser storage (`cookies`, `localStorage`…)

In your case, since a cookie is registered after login, you can simply make a call on load to your API which validate the cookie and send you the user, like so:

```
"use client";

import { createContext, useContext, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";

const host = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_HOST;
export const AdminAuthContext = createContext({});
export const AdminAuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const router = useRouter(); // Initialize useRouter

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null); // State to store admin user details
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    /* 
      Use the right API endpoint to get the user. If there is a cookie, 
      from a previous login, you should get the user 
      as when you just logged in
   */
    const checkAdminLogin = async () => {
      try {
        const request = await fetch(`${host}/api/admin/user`, {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: "include",
        });

        if (request.ok) {
          const res = await request.json();
          setUser(res.username);
        } else {
          throw new Error("Not authorized");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        router.push("/admin/login");
      } finally {
        setLoading(false);
      }
    };
    checkAdminLogin();
  }, [router]);

  const doAdminLogin = async (email, password) => {
    // ...
  };

  const doAdminLogout = async () => {
    // ...
  };

  return (
    <AdminAuthContext.Provider value={{ user, doAdminLogin, doAdminLogout }}>
      {loading ? "Loading..." : children}
    </AdminAuthContext.Provider>
  );
};

export function useAdminAuthContext() {
  return useContext(AdminAuthContext);
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! Would checkAdminLogin() function automatically pick up the token cookie to get the user? If not, how would I know which user is making the request in my backend?

Comment: `fetch` with `credentials: "include"` will send automatically cookies in cross-origin requests and  `credentials: "same-origin"` (the default) will send cookies set by the domain serving the your front end application.

Comment: Unless you are using a `Bareer` Authorization header, one of the two above config work on its own. And if you are using a `Bareer`, you need to grab the cookie with JavaScript and set the header `Autorization: "Bareer " + token`.

Comment: Okay, that was something I wasn't aware of (the fact that cookies get sent automatically with `credentials: "include`). On the other hand, yes, I am actually using a `Bearer` token for authentication in my backend so that's why I am struggling to make it work because I need to retrieve the cookie's value which is the jwt token to set it in the `Authentication` header from AdminAuthContext. As the Context is client-side it can't (and I believe it shouldn't) be able to retrieve the cookie by itself but then I am back to starting point.

Comment: You should either change your backend to receive a cookie and not a Bearer header, or allow the client to access the cookie and set it as Bearer. You cannot do otherwise.

Comment: Yeah, just double checked NextJS Authentication docs and it clearly states `Each subsequent server request includes this cookie, minimizing the need for repeated server queries and enhancing client-side efficiency.` I don't know how I skipped that part. Also looking in MDN docs, it seems it's just the way cookies work I just didn't understand it. So yeah I will have to change my backend to work with cookies. The thing is I was used to work with JWT token returned in the login response and then passing it around.

Answer (score 1):

You're always going to lose component level state on page navigation. Redux internally attaches things to the window object to avoid this. I'd recommend either using redux, maybe even with a persistant storage plugin if you want the storage to persist even further, but redux alone should handle this for you without your current issue.